# Why use Developer identity or third party to authenticate via backend

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, parse-platform, amazon-cognito

In the IOS SDK S3TransferManager Sample provided as an example by Amazon Web Services it looks as if I can access AWS resources like s3 without having to go through authentication providers like Facebook or Google. So what is the purpose of having my own developer identity or authenticating through the backend instead of on mobile if I'm using Parse? For example I believe Parse uses front end authentication (on mobile) to authenticate users rather than backend authentication using their Cloud Code  service(https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#cloud-code)

```
"Cloud Code is easy to use because it's built on the same JavaScript 
SDK that powers thousands of apps. The only difference is that this  
code runs in the Parse Cloud rather than running on a mobile device."
```

couldn't I just authenticate users with parse on the front end and when succeeded just copy and past this code below into the success block?

```
// Authenticate with Parse and if authentication succeeded execute code below
AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider = [[AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider alloc]
                                                      initWithRegionType:AWSRegionUSEast1
                                                      identityPoolId:@"identity-pool"];

AWSServiceConfiguration *configuration = [[AWSServiceConfiguration alloc] initWithRegion:AWSRegionUSEast1 credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider];

[AWSServiceManager defaultServiceManager].defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration;
```

and still have access to my aws resources. That way I don't need to use the AWSCredentialsProvider protocol that needs the access key, secret key, and session key sent to my app from the backend. Plus it seems like the IOS SDK manages allocating token sessions by itself (automatically) on mobile, is my thinking correct or am I missing something? still new to this so sorry if I sound ignorant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cognito delegates credentials based on two different kinds of scopes - unauthenticated and authenticated. The power these types of users is defined by the unauth and auth roles, which are created with and linked to the identity pool used. The S3 demo was using unauthenticated users, which is why they didn't require some provider. If you don't have some external need and are only thinking about using Cognito for credentials, unauthenticated users is all you would need. They work on their own. See the [Cognito developer guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/devguide/identity/getting-credentials/) for more information.

Cognito supports Facebook, Twitter, Digits, Amazon, Google, OIDC providers, and developer authenticated identities to authenticate users. If you were looking to use Parse to authenticate users, you would need to use them as a developer authenticated provider.

To be clear, though, that wouldn't mean your backend has to send access key/secret key...etc. to your device. [This blog post](https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx2FL1QAPDE0UAH/Understanding-Amazon-Cognito-Authentication-Part-2-Developer-Authenticated-Ident) covers it in better detail, but the app would send the login credentials to your backend. This backend would validate those and get an identityId/token from Cognito. These would be sent back to the device, which would then send back out to get credentials to access AWS.